# Relu No algorithm worked in 8 channel Unet

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

During the training process, I noticed that all the datasets, such as train1day, train2day, etc., are being grouped into the same class. How can I separate them into seven classes?

classes problem

```
Found 33 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 38 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 98 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

I encountered the following error in the middle of training. How can I resolve it? I tried adding the following code and adjusting the batch size based on methods like ChatGPT, but it didn't work.

(These codes were found from ChatGPT and other people's inquiries.)

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

error message

```
NotFoundError
 No algorithm worked!
     [[node model/conv2d/Relu (defined at C:\Labbb\unet_mao0\main.py:87) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2655]

Function call stack:
train_function
  File "C:\Labbb\unet_mao0\main.py", line 87, in <module>
```

main.py

```
folders = [
    'data/syu/train1day/auto_correlation1_reverse',
    'data/syu/train1day/energy1',
    'data/syu/train1day/entropy1_reverse',
    'data/syu/train1day/homogeneity1',
    'data/syu/train1day/temprature',
    'data/syu/train1day/clahe1',

    train2day train3day....

    'data/syu/train7day/auto_correlation7_reverse',
    'data/syu/train7day/energy7',
    'data/syu/train7day/entropy7_reverse',
    'data/syu/train7day/homogeneity7',
    'data/syu/train7day/temprature',
    'data/syu/train7day/clahe7'
]

myGene = trainGenerator(4, folders,'image','label',data_gen_args,save_to_dir = None)
model = unet(input_size=(512, 512, 8))
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weight/unet_8channels.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
train_history=model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=20,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])_____line87
```